# Rare pets more useful in upcoming pet battles?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have a number of rare pets that I've obtained over the years, and I'm curious as to whether or not these pets, because of their rarity, will be more useful than the easier to obtain pets in the upcoming pet battles of MoP.

Comment: More useful how?  Vanity pets sound like they're the definition of useless.

Comment: I removed the word "vanity", as its a bit misleading from what I'm asking here. I simply want to know if the pets that took me more work to obtain will therefore be more useful in the pet battles system.

Comment: rare is also used to define a "blue" item in wow and now pets can have that type of quality so that is not a good word to use either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quality of the pet(can bee seen by the color of the name plate) decides how much stat a pet gains each level, so a rare quality pet(blue name plate) will be better than a common quality pet(white name plate) in the long run.

Originally all non-captured pet where of common quality (white), but blizzard have changed it so some of the harder to get pets will be of rare quality(blue).

An updated list can be found [at the blue post](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/6080522555).

But the list of higher quality non-captured pets as I write this looks like this:

- Brilliant Kaliri
- Celestial Dragon
- Feral Vermling
- Jade Tentacle
- Kirin Tor Familiar
- Little Fawn
- Nuts
- Stinker
- Clockwork Gnome
- Crawling Claw
- Fossilized Hatchling
- Pterrodax Hatchling
- Voodoo Figurine
- Murkimus
- Core Hound Pup
- Cenarion Hatchling
- Gryphon Hatchling
- Guardian Cub
- Lil' K.T.
- Lil' Ragnaros
- Lil' XT
- Moonkin Hatchling
- Pandaren Monk
- Soul of the Aspects
- Wind Rider Cub
- Deathy
- Grunty
- Murkablo
- Murky
- Fetish Shaman
- Frosty
- Lil' Deathwing
- Lucky Quilen Cub
- Lurky
- Mini Thor
- Netherwhelp
- Panda Cub
- Mini Diablo
- Zergling
- Darkmoon Balloon
- Darkmoon Cub
- Darkmoon Monkey
- Darkmoon Tonk
- Darkmoon Turtle
- Darkmoon Zeppelin
- Azure Whelpling
- Crimson Whelpling
- Dark Whelpling
- Emerald Whelpling
- Firefly
- Fox Kit
- Gundrak Hatchling
- Hyacinth Macaw
- Razzashi Hatchling
- Sprite Darter Hatchling
- Phoenix Hatchling
- Chuck
- Giant Sewer Rat
- Magical Crawdad
- Muckbreath
- Snarly
- Strand Crawler
- Toothy
- Dark Phoenix Hatchling
- Elementium Geode
- Crimson Lasher
- Hyjal Bear Cub
- Searing Scorhling
- Panther Cub
- Pebble
- Disguisting Oozeling
- Mr. Grubbs
- Tiny Shale Spider
- Bananas
- Dragon Kite
- Ethereal Soul-Trader
- Eye of the Legion
- Gregarious Grell
- Hippogryph Hatchling
- Landro's Lichling
- Landro's Lil' XT
- Nightsaber Cub
- Purple puffer
- Rocket Chicken
- Sand Scarab
- Spectral Tiger Cub
- Tuskarr Kite
- Lumpy
- Baby Blizzard Bear
- Onyxian Whelpling
- Lucky
- Mini Tyrael
- Lashtail Hatchling

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Blem. I'm glad to see that all of my efforts over the years might be useful for something else other than simply showing them off. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Some pets may have some different abilities or feature cosmetic differences, but no player will ever have a significant advantage based simply on the rarity of a pet.

Source : [Interview with the lead quest designer](http://www.wowhead.com/news=196641/blizzcon-2011-exclusive-interview-with-dave-kosak-wow-lead-quest-designer)